# Docker compose network doesn't bind ip address

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run a selenium grid from a docker compose file. In this docker compose I set an Ip address, because I want to run test on a jenkins from another docker image. Only when I try to run my tests with the setup ip address it gives following error

```
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException at RemoteWebDriver.java:573
        Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException at InetAddress.java:800
```

This is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 3000
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 3000

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    container_name: web-automation_chrome
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 4
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 4
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9001:5900"
    links:
      - hub
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2  

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    container_name: web-automation_firefox
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 2
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 2
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9002:5900"
    links:
      - hub
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.3  
networks:
  testing_net:
    ipam: 
        driver: default
        config:
            - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

When I go to 172.28.1.1:4444 I don't reach the selenium hub

Comment: You shouldn't need any of the manual network configuration you have here; you should be able to delete all of the `networks:`, `links:`, and `container_name:` blocks without any ill effects, and the `chrome` container will be able to use `hub` as a host name.  This setup is described further in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: The linking of the chrome container to the hub isn't the issue. I want to run testcase on the hub, and these test run from another jenkins container.